# Automate opening a program and files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a script (Python 3x) which, looks in a specific network folder, and logs all the sub folders and creates a list, which each item looks a bit like this:

```
Z:\Clients\xxx\2. RAW Export\2nd Road Loading +\"2nd (1).fls" "2nd (10).fls" "2nd (11).fls" "2nd (12).fls" "2nd (13).fls" "2nd (14).fls" "2nd (15).fls" "2nd (16).fls" "2nd (17).fls" "2nd (18).fls" "2nd (19).fls" "2nd (2).fls" "2nd (3).fls" "2nd (4).fls" "2nd (5).fls" "2nd (6).fls" "2nd (7).fls" "2nd (8).fls" "2nd (9).fls" "new project (2) Support" "new project (2).rcp" "new project (3) Support" "new project (3).rcp" "new project Support" "new project.rcp"
```

The reason being is, i want to be able to open the required program (which I have done), which then asks for the folder location and files, and then the copied text (above) will get copied into the 'open' files window:

The code that creates this:

```
import os

def sysPathCreator(rootFolder):
   #rootFolder = ("C:\\Users\\ALS_Surveying\\Desktop\\test folder")

   # Creates a list of all subfolders
   subFolderList2 = os.listdir(rootFolder)

   # Deletes any elements from a list if they are a file not a folder
   subFolderList = [x for x in subFolderList2 if "." not in x]

   # This create the full path to each subfolder
   subFolderList2 = []
   for a in subFolderList:
      temp = os.path.join(rootFolder,a)
      subFolderList2.append(temp)

   # How many subfolders in root
   totalSubFolders = len(subFolderList)

   # Creates a List holding a single value for all contents in each subfolder
   fileList = []
   stepper = 0
   for fl in range(totalSubFolders):
      fileList.append(os.listdir(subFolderList2[stepper]))
      stepper = stepper + 1

   # Create the final list holding the full path, root to files
   filePathList = []
   stepper = 0
   for final in range(totalSubFolders):
      subFolderList2Var = str(subFolderList2[stepper])
      fileListVar = str(fileList[stepper])
      temp2 = os.path.join(subFolderList2Var,fileListVar)
      stepper = stepper + 1
      filePathList.append(temp2)

   # Remove values from strings within list (Clean up)
   for i, v in enumerate(filePathList) :
       filePathList[i] = v.replace(",","")
   for i, v in enumerate(filePathList) :
       filePathList[i] = v.replace("[","")
   for i, v in enumerate(filePathList) :
       filePathList[i] = v.replace("]","")
   for i, v in enumerate(filePathList) :
       filePathList[i] = v.replace("'","\"") # This is supposed to have three """

   # Print
   for abc in filePathList:
      print(abc)
   print()

   print(" Paths created - Successfully".rjust(35,"*"))
   #Return List
   return(filePathList)

#rootFolder = ("C:\\Users\\ALS_Surveying\\Desktop\\test folder")
#sysPathCreator(rootFolder)
```

But I get an error:
"Files not found"
Even though if within the open window, you select all the files it created the exact same format, like above; any ideas?

Comment: Please see my question, for updated information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with using `os.walk`:

```
import os

def sysPathCreator(rootFolder):
   #rootFolder = ("C:\\Users\\ALS_Surveying\\Desktop\\test folder")

   fullPaths = []
   t = os.walk(rootFolder)
   for pathh,dir,files in t: 
        fullPaths.extend( [os.path.join(pathh,f) for f in files])

   asText = '"' + '"\n"'.join(fullPaths) + '"'

   return asText

rootFolder = "C:\\Users\\ALS_Surveying\\Desktop\\test folder"
t = sysPathCreator(rootFolder)
print(t)
```

this will contain all files of your directory. Try to feed that to your 3rd party program. I have a hunch that it eat it and be happy about it.

If that does not work, replace

```
asText = '"' + '"\n"'.join(fullPaths) + '"'
```

with

```
asText = '"' + '" "'.join(fullPaths) + '"'
```

and try again.

Comment: This still produces the same error that the file names and folders cant be found

Comment: I have done a video explaining what its try to do and the error i get: https://youtu.be/8sDwmKjP0LM

Comment: The code worked but would only open 3 or 4 files? Not all the files in the folder?

Comment: @LewisBoxer Try to count how much data it takes- from the looks of it I think it will read about 256 or 512  characters  - thats the max length of a filename in windows. Guess the program cuts it there - sorry. Try to start the program with `/?    /help    -? --?` and see if they got a commandline interface.  You own list implementation should also put the path into " "  as it contains spaces - windows paths with spaces have to be given in "" else windows cant understand it.

Comment: The first program is 256 characters, its working if i push the path first like:  Z:\Clients\xxx\2. RAW Export\                                                 
Then the file names like: "2nd (1).fls" "2nd (10).fls" "2nd (11).fls" "2nd (12).fls" "2nd (13).fls" "2nd (14).fls" "2nd (15).fls", but im gona struggle cause it only takes 256, any other ideas

Comment: Can you create a .bat file or something, which could be opened by my program and that .bat would hold all the information for the batch load?

Comment: @LewisBoxer  Can your program save "solution files" or something like that? If they are pure text you could write that as python script and load it on the commandline with your stiching program. No idea if its feasable - maybe there is some kind of forum for your 3rd party app that you can ask?